# Generalize a function for an ODE solver

Tags: python, ode

I have the next system of equations:

```
#dY0=/dt = k1*S - k2*Y1*Y0
#dY1/dt = k3*S - k4*Y1
```

Where S(t) is a staircase function that increases by one unit at t = 4, 8, 12 and so on. My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def stp(t):
   if t < 4 and t >= 0:
        return 0.0
   if t < 8 and t >= 4:
        return 1.0
   if t < 12 and t >= 8:
        return 2.0
   if t < 16 and t >= 12:
        return 3.0
   if t < 20 and t >= 16:
        return 4.0
   else:
        return 5.0

#Initial conditions:
y0 = np.array([1,0])

#Time
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

def f(y,t):
    s=stp(t)
    k1=2
    k2=2
    k3=1
    k4=1
    dy0=k1*s - k2*y[1]*y[0]
    dy1=k3*s - k4*y[1]
    return (dy0, dy1)

res=odeint(f, y0, t)
```

My question is, how my "stp" function would be improved in order to do not write down as many conditions as time points I specify? (it ends in giving 5 as the returned value just to end the function, but should be increasing if time length increases too), I mean, to make it general for any time length as well as being able to specify different intervals for the jumps of the piecewise function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stp` has a well defined relationship with respect to parameter `t`. You can replace all `t < 20` with an integer division:

```
def stp(t):
   if t < 20:
       return float(t//4)
   else:
       return 5.0
```

And generally, for all ranges, including those far beyond 20:

```
def stp(t):
    return float(t//4)
```